# How can i reduce navybar height

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am just a learner in html and i am working on a template, now i need to reduce the size of the navbar  a bit, i have succeeded in increasing size by just incresing the margin at the bolded words here down but i cant reduce size, Pls help. here is the code and attachaed the picture with the navybar bar or just click https://giramisi.host/ to see the real site live

css navbar code

```html
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box,
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box>li+li {
margin-left: 59px;
}
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box>li {
position: relative;
padding: 33px 0px 33px;
}
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box>li>a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
color: var(--thm-gray);
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
text-transform: capitalize;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
z-index: 1;
}
.main-nav__main-navigation .main-nav__navigation-box>li>a:before {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: -10px;
right: 0;
height: 0px;
background: var(--thm-primary);
content: "";
transform: scaleX(0.5);
opacity: 0;
transition: all 500ms ease;
z-index: -1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying adding the below code:

```
.main-nav__header-two__content-box {
height:90px;
}
```

Comment: When i add in my destop editor it changes but when i take it online, no changes

Comment: Try putting like this "height:90px !important;"

Comment: Thanks Ugene, everything worked well, Bravooo